# Intersection points between circle and line with straights off

Tags: javascript, svg, jsxgraph

I am using intersection objects to show 2 intersection points between a circle and a line that is not infinite (straightFirst and straightLast are false).

JSX graph is treating that line as infinite even though I set alwaysIntersect false, here's my script:

```
var line = app.board.create('line', [[-2,-2],[1,1]], {straightFirst:false, straightLast:false })
var circle = app.board.create('circle', [[0,0],[-2,0]], { })
app.board.create('intersection', [line, circle, 0], {alwaysIntersect:false})
app.board.create('intersection', [line, circle, 1], {alwaysIntersect:false})
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output (it should show one point only, because the other one is not intersected)

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [segment](https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/Segment.html) for a line segment?

Comment: @Ouroborus segment is exactly the line but with properties straightFirst and straightLast false.

Comment: I played around with this a bit and took a look at the library's code. It seems like it should be working as you intend but clearly isn't. I suspect this may be a bug in the library. They're on github so there's an [issue tracker](https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/issues).

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you, I will open an issue there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! It is fixed in the sources and will be available in tomorrow's nightly build.

Comment: @AlfredWassermann Thank you very much I appreciate your effort.